# Linphone (3.9.1) compiling error with ./prepare.py --package in OS X El Capitan (10.11.4)

Tags: software-installation, osx, voip

I had clone the [linphone-desktop](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-desktop) project and follow all the steps provided both on the README and in the README.macos from the [linphone repository](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone) to install all the dependencies, by the way I'm using MacPorts 2.3.4.

So, I have an error compiling after I ran the prepare.py script with the --package option. But the thing is that when I ran the prepare.py script without the --package option and compile again it works just fine.

Output from iTerm:

```
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Release"
Cannot find source to copy: /Users/pvaldivieso/Downloads/linphone-desktop/OUTPUT/lib/mediastreamer/plugins/*.*.dylib
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/install_name_tool: can't open file: /Users/pvaldivieso/Downloads/linphone-desktop/WORK/PACKAGE/Linphone.app/Contents/MacOS/Linphone-bin (No such file or directory)
/usr/bin/patch: **** Can't find file /Users/pvaldivieso/Downloads/linphone-desktop/WORK/PACKAGE/Linphone.app/Contents/Resources/share/themes/Quartz/gtk-2.0/gtkrc : No such file or directory
pkgbuild: error: Component path "/Users/pvaldivieso/Downloads/linphone-desktop/WORK/PACKAGE/Linphone.app" does not exist.
[100%] Completed 'TARGET_linphone_package'
[100%] Built target TARGET_linphone_package
```

It goes all the way to the end and fails. I think it's related to mediastreamer and not finding some .dylib but I'm not sure.

My question is: how to generate the installation package for Mac OS X?

Comment: Is there no pre-existing OS X package for linphone then?

Comment: They have one on the [website](http://www.linphone.org/technical-corner/linphone/downloads), but I want to change the source code of the interface

Comment: Could you rebuild a modified package from source?

Comment: I can build it from source but I can't create the installation package for it

Comment: Can't you use the OS X package build, whatever it is?

Comment: There is a tool called gtk-mac-bundler (which they use in linphone to generate the installation package), I haven't look at it because I was trying to fix my issue with the --package option first. But I will check that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I did manage to solve this a long time ago but I forgot about the question, I'm posting the answer in case someone came up with this.

The thing is that the .dylib files are missing and the XML file used by gtk-mac-bundler is missing a line that tells the bundler where to put those .dylib insisde the .app.

So, in the file `submodules/cmake-builder/configs/desktop/linphone_package/mac-bundler/linphone.bundle` I added:

```
<binary>
  ${prefix:linphone}/lib/*.dylib
</binary>
```

That's all.